# How to change table data to unreadable format in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I created a table in PostgreSQL and inserted some data in that table.

I want to change that data from readable to unreadable format because I want to restrict the user to read that data not with authentication only with data.

Comment: just our of curiosity, why can't you revoke the select rights from users / roles that aren't supposed to read the table's content?

Comment: such as `REVOKE SELECT ON tb1 FROM username;`

Comment: It was REVOKE but user is able to run the query which is related to SELECT and INSERT and able to see the info

Comment: you can go wild :-D  `REVOKE SELECT,INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE ON tb1 FROM username;` or `REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON tb1 FROM username;`